# PS to list all schemas

Tags: powershell

This may be simple enough.But since I am new to powershell handling sql script,I am here with a question.

After getting connected to a database how can we retrieve all the schema's listed in that particular database? Can anyone provide me a sample script of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

```
# I like to use SMO. There are other ways, arguably just as good.
# You need to make sure that the SMO library is loaded. 
# If it already is loaded, you don't need this line. 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null 

# I'm using integrated security. 
# If you aren't, you will need to add a username and password here.
# substitute your server name in place of localhost 
$server = New-Object ([Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.SMO.Server]) "localhost"

# Substitute your database name in place of 
AdventureWorks $Database = $server.Databases | where {$_.Name -match "AdventureWorks"}
$Database.Schemas | Format-Table Name

# if you want to see schemas in all databases in one list, this should work 
$server.Databases.Schemas | format-table Parent,Name
```

Comment: Thanks darin..When I try to execute the code it shows Cannot find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server]: make sure the assembly containing this type is l oaded. Iam trying to load the dll like this.. [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('D:\VysakhTest\Microsoft.SqlSe‌​rver.Management.Smo.Server') | out-null Am I doing anything wrong??There is no smo dll found in my server so i couldnt test my code.Please help me out on this..

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using on the server? What happens if you run it from your workstation?

Comment: @darin strait: Now I am able to connect with that particular server/instance. but how can I get the schemas associated with a particular db,that is already referred in my xml file.
    AdventureWorks $Database = $server.Databases | where {$_.Name -match "AdventureWorks"}
    $Database.Schemas | Format-Table Name
and $server.Databases.Schemas | format-table Parent,Name

doesnt work for me...Please help..

Comment: What xml file? Have you looked at using the xml data type?